# Android 4.3 specific crash calling PackageManager.getDrawable()

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm getting a hard crash in my app on devices running Android 4.3. The code in question works flawlessly on Android 4.2 and below.

I have traced the error to a call to `mPackageManager.getDrawable()`. Every so often, calling this function results in my app being terminated (without an exception being raised). Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

The output is as follows (full log is [here](http://pastebin.com/cqzZkbtt)):

````
08-17 12:03:37.036: I/DEBUG(177): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-17 12:03:37.036: I/DEBUG(177): Build fingerprint:'google/razor/flo:4.3/JSS15J/748593:user/release-keys'
08-17 12:03:37.036: I/DEBUG(177): Revision: '0'
08-17 12:03:37.036: I/DEBUG(177): pid: 5687, tid: 5812, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> com.chrislacy.actionlauncher.pro <<<
08-17 12:03:37.036: I/DEBUG(177): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00005d68
08-17 12:03:37.186: I/DEBUG(177):     r0 74918cd0  r1 00005d68  r2 000001a8  r3 00000000
08-17 12:03:37.186: I/DEBUG(177):     r4 0000007a  r5 0000007a  r6 74918eb8  r7 0000007a
08-17 12:03:37.186: I/DEBUG(177):     r8 00005d68  r9 0000007a  sl 00000000  fp 00000000
08-17 12:03:37.186: I/DEBUG(177):     ip 4046dd38  sp 7aa261a0  lr 402bff88  pc 400a8e00  cpsr 28030010

... (snip)

08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177): backtrace:
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #00  pc 0001ce00  /system/lib/libc.so (memcpy+120)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #01  pc 00074f84  /system/lib/libskia.so
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #02  pc 000744f8  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkBitmapProcShader::shadeSpan(int, int, unsigned int*, int)+52)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #03  pc 00085a70  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkARGB32_Shader_Blitter::blitRect(int, int, int, int)+568)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #04  pc 000cba2c  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillIRect(SkIRect const&, SkRegion const*, SkBlitter*)+368)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #05  pc 000cbb24  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillRect(SkRect const&, SkRegion const*, SkBlitter*)+152)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #06  pc 000cbc90  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkScan::FillRect(SkRect const&, SkRasterClip const&, SkBlitter*)+84)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #07  pc 0009b078  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkDraw::drawRect(SkRect const&, SkPaint const&) const+660)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #08  pc 0008d754  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkCanvas::drawRect(SkRect const&, SkPaint const&)+696)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #09  pc 0008f9ec  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkCanvas::drawRectCoords(float, float, float, float, SkPaint const&)+44)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #10  pc 0001dc4c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #11  pc 0004decf  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #12  pc 00027060  /system/lib/libdvm.so
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #13  pc 0002b5ec  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #14  pc 0005ff21  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+292)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #15  pc 0005ff4b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #16  pc 00054ccb  /system/lib/libdvm.so
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #17  pc 0000ca58  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
08-17 12:03:37.196: I/DEBUG(177):     #18  pc 0000cbd4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)

... (snip)

08-17 12:03:37.516: W/ActivityManager(523):   Force finishing activity com.chrislacy.actionlauncher.pro/com.chrislacy.launcher.Launcher
08-17 12:03:37.546: I/WindowState(523): WIN DEATH: Window{423d8448 u0 com.chrislacy.actionlauncher.pro/com.chrislacy.launcher.Launcher}
08-17 12:03:37.556: I/ActivityManager(523): Process com.chrislacy.actionlauncher.pro (pid 5687) has died.```
````

Comment: What made you trace it to that call? Looking at the backtrace, it appears to be something to do with drawing calls in an AsyncTask, but it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: I added `Log.d()` calls to isolate where execution stopped. `AsyncTask #1` is the name of the thread this crash occurred in, but the `getDrawable()` call is made from the `doInBackground()` of an `AsyncTask` instance.

Comment: Are there any other concurrent tasks that might be running at the same time? I know it's a stretch, it just seems like an unlikely stack trace for a getter method.

Comment: Chris, did you figure out the cause of this crash?

Comment: suggestion: check if the crash happens on the UI thread. In general, Android assumes that UI is done on the UI thread (and it is arguable whether _getDrawable()_ is this _doing-UI_)